# jQuery else if not working

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have the following function but the else if statement doesn't work properly, only the first one is working.

There's a function to switch between .grid and .grid-sm but this only makes the selected grid icon ative or inactive. It also changes on click..

Could you please give me any advice ? Thank you

```
function blockHover(status) {

var screenLg = $('body').find('.container').width() == 1170;

if ($('.product_list').is('.grid')) {

    $(document).off('mouseenter').on('mouseenter', '.product_list.grid li.ajax_block_product .product-container', function(e) {
        if (screenLg) {
            var pcHeight = $(this).parent().outerHeight();
            var pcPHeight = $(this).parent().find('.button-container').outerHeight() + $(this).parent().find('.comments_note').outerHeight() + $(this).parent().find('.functional-buttons').outerHeight();
            $(this).parent().addClass('hovered');
            $(this).find('.button-container').show();
        }
    });

    $(document).off('mouseleave').on('mouseleave', '.product_list.grid li.ajax_block_product .product-container', function(e) {
        if (screenLg) {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('hovered');
            $(this).find('.button-container').hide();
        }
    });

} else if ($('.product_list').is('.grid-sm')) {

    $('.product_list .info-grid-sm').show();

    $(document).off('mouseenter').on('mouseenter', '.grid-sm li.ajax_block_product.gr-sm .product-container', function(e) {
        if (screenLg) {
            var pcHeight = $(this).parent().outerHeight();
            var pcPHeight = $(this).parent().find('.button-container').outerHeight() + $(this).parent().find('.comments_note').outerHeight() + $(this).parent().find('.functional-buttons').outerHeight();
            $(this).parent().addClass('hovered');
            $(this).find('.info-grid-sm').removeClass('hide');
        }
    });

    $(document).off('mouseleave').on('mouseleave', '.grid-sm li.ajax_block_product.gr-sm .product-container', function(e) {
        if (screenLg) {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('hovered');
            $(this).find('.info-grid-sm').addClass('hide');
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Do you run the function after changing the class?

Comment: No, it doesn't run more after changing the class. It loads the class on document load

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that, I added the function to the document on click function and now it's working when I switch the grid. But if the second grid (grid-sm) stays through other page, the hover function doesn't work..